# Which merge should be used so all columns show data needed on Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, join

Does anyone know how to merge tables in pandas and have all the columns show the data, instead of some showing NaN. I am think it is because I chose left join however I do no know which join to use that displays whole data set.
[merge image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRBVd.png)

I attached an image to show what it is displaying.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a sample input with expected output clearly stating what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like maybe you want an outer join. Check out the pandas merge docs. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html

`how=outer` is the keyword argument to make it an outer join. You may still get null values.

You can do an inner join if you just want to keep rows that match on some column or index.